# Which method gets called every time a subclassed uibutton gets called?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, init

I subclassed a `UIButton`, and I want to give all instances of my `newButton` the same background image, among other things.  I thought I found the right init method in `initWithCoder`, but it just gets called for the first `newButton`.  I did a little test by changing the text size to something massive, and only the first `newButton`s text size was changed.

I can use `drawRect:`, and it works just fine.  But I was told that is not a good method to use.

Does anyone know which method will get called, so that I can make some adjustments?

```
 @implementation LCHButton

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self setDefaults];
}
return self;
}

 -(id)init
 {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    [self setDefaults];
}
return self;

}

 -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
 {
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    [self setDefaults];
}
return self;
}

 -(void)setDefaults
 {
[self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"submitBtn.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo-500" size:17];
}

 @end
```

This will change only the first button

Comment: Are you creating all of your buttons in a XIB or storyboard, or are you creating them in code?

Comment: 1. It is not recommended to `subclass` `UIButton`. A lot of different problems could occur in future. 2. Try to set background in `- (void)awakeFromNib{}` method of `UIButton`